Should a Catholic listen to their conscience or the Archbishop in matters concerning their posture at Mass?
Archibishop Cupich asked his flock to not kneel before receiving communion: Cardinal Cupich Asks Catholics ‘to Receive Holy Communion Standing’ in Chicago Archdiocese.
But I took a personal vow to always receive communion kneeling and on the tongue.
In general, should a Catholic follow his or her own conscience in matters like this or abide by the reasoned dictates of an Archbishop?  Or, to put another way, what level of fealty does a Catholic have to their Bishop in personal liturgical practices which are allowed by canon law?

Having read the letter from the Cardinal now, I am not convinced that he is giving a command not to kneel. Instead, the letter just says not to make any gestures which call attention to oneself. I personally don't think that kneeling calls attention to oneself, but I'm sure others may disagree. As he has phrased it, I believe that he is, intentionally or not, leaving this up to prudential judgment.

@jaredad7 They covered it on the Dec 13th loopcast it was clear that Cdl. Cupich couldn't tell everyone not to kneel, but everyone in the diocese will understand it that way.

If he can't tell everyone not to kneel, then you may kneel.

I don't have relevant knowledge to contribute, but I would guess, since a church tribunal may find a marriage to have been invalid, that a church tribunal may find another vow to have been invalid by a similar process and for similar reasons.

Should a Catholic listen to their conscience or the Archbishop in matters concerning their posture at Mass?
One should always obey the dictates of one’s conscience, especially a conscience that is well formed, moulded and guided in the teachings and traditions of the Church.
In regards to the letter of Cardinal Cupich’s letter requesting Catholics to receive Holy Communion while standing only and not while kneeling, one freedom to kneel down when receiving Communion is still an option.

Cardinal Blase Cupich of the Archdiocese of Chicago, in a letter published this week in the archdiocesan newspaper, urged Catholics to stand while receiving Holy Communion and not make gestures that draw attention to oneself.
In the letter, published in Chicago Catholic, Cardinal Cupich said “the norm established by [the] Holy See for the universal Church and approved by the U.S. Conference of Catholic Bishops is for the faithful to process together as an expression of their coming forward as the body of Christ and to receive holy Communion standing.”
The cardinal goes on to state that “nothing should be done to impede any of these processions” and that “disrupting this moment only diminishes this powerful symbolic expression, by which the faithful in processing together express their faith that they are called to become the very Body of Christ they receive.”
Cardinal Cupich Asks Catholics ‘to Receive Holy Communion Standing’ in Chicago Archdiocese

The Cardinal does not forbid receiving Communion while one is kneeling. He is clearly encouraging the faithful to stand when going to communion.
Besides this fact, the Cardinal can not know the proper internal dispositions of more traditional Catholics to receive Communion while one their knees as an act of supernatural piety towards the Sacred Body of Christ.
Even Rome permits both kinds of liturgical posture while going to Communion.

[90.] “The faithful should receive Communion kneeling or standing, as the Conference of Bishops will have determined”, with its acts having received the recognitio of the Apostolic See. “However, if they receive Communion standing, it is recommended that they give due reverence before the reception of the Sacrament, as set forth in the same norms”.
[91.] In distributing Holy Communion it is to be remembered that “sacred ministers may not deny the sacraments to those who seek them in a reasonable manner, are rightly disposed, and are not prohibited by law from receiving them”. Hence any baptized Catholic who is not prevented by law must be admitted to Holy Communion. Therefore, it is not licit to deny Holy Communion to any of Christ’s faithful solely on the grounds, for example, that the person wishes to receive the Eucharist kneeling or standing.
[92.] Although each of the faithful always has the right to receive Holy Communion on the tongue, at his choice, if any communicant should wish to receive the Sacrament in the hand, in areas where the Bishops’ Conference with the recognitio of the Apostolic See has given permission, the sacred host is to be administered to him or her. However, special care should be taken to ensure that the host is consumed by the communicant in the presence of the minister, so that no one goes away carrying the Eucharistic species in his hand. If there is a risk of profanation, then Holy Communion should not be given in the hand to the faithful.
Redemptionis Sacramentum On certain matters to be observed or to be avoided regarding the Most Holy Eucharist

I personally find it offensive that Cardinal Blasé Cupich thinks that receiving the Holy Eucharist on one’s knees seems to imply that such faithful are drawing ”attention to themselves”. After all the consecrated host is the Body of Christ! It only fitting to receive it on one’s knees!!!
Cardinal Cupich especially does not have the authority to stop the faithful from receiving communion on tongues.

+1 upvoted for a clear and authoritative answer . You should always listen to your conscience because church leaders are men and they can be compromised

"One should always obey the dictates of one’s conscience, especially a conscience that is well formed, moulded and guided in the teachings and traditions of the Church." I would say one should always obey one's conscience only if it is well formed, etc. It is possible for a malformed conscience to lead one astray, and most consciences today are likely malformed.

In matters such as this, one needs to be obedient to the bishop of his diocese, as his bishop is his superior. Now, what exactly that means will be nuanced. The bishop may only make a recommendation or request, and such does not necessarily need to be obeyed. If the bishop gives a just command, that needs to be obeyed, and a just command here is defined as a command which the giver has the authority to give. The bishop is not in this particular case commanding the faithful to commit sin, and he does have the authority to dictate the particulars regarding liturgical actions in his jurisdiction. Hence, if the cardinal actually gave a command (and did not merely express his personal opinion or desire, or merely make a request), then the faithful are bound to obey it (I'm editing this to correct a point of fact; the Holy See has in fact ruled that the faithful cannot be denied communion for kneeling, which would seem to indicate that the Cardinal does not in fact have the right to require standing, but I think that if we suppose he hypothetically does, this answer is still valuable for possible future conflicts).
As to the matter of your vow, we should examine canon 1194 of the 1983 code, which says "A vow ceases by the lapse of the time designated to fulfill the obligation, by a substantial change of the matter promised, by the absence of a condition on which the vow depends, by the absence of the purpose of the vow, by dispensation, or by commutation." In my judgement, if you live in Chicago and Cardinal Cupich has really given a command (and we should take care to verify that he has), then there is now an absence of a condition on which your vow depends, namely, that you have the religious right to choose to kneel for communion. If your bishop has taken that right away, you no longer have it, and having it is a necessary condition for the fulfillment of your vow. Hence, the vow has now ceased (assuming everything said above is really true).
Furthermore, as this is a private vow, you might be able to commute it yourself under Cano 1197, which says "The person who makes a private vow can commute the work promised by the vow into a better or equal good; however, one who has the power of dispensing according to the norm of can. 1196 can commute it into a lesser good." You could commute your vow to a higher good, and it may serve you well to seek counsel on this from a trusted pastor if you are considering this route. But, I think this is a secondary concern. In my estimation, the vow has ceased because it has become impossible to fulfill due to unforeseeable changes in circumstances (assuming the Cardinal really has given a command).
Finally, to the question of conscience, one must follow a well-formed conscience above all else, but a well-formed conscience will compel one to be obedient to the bishop. Canon law seems to make provision regarding your vow such that a crisis of conscience should not really exist.
On obeying sinful superiors
A greater explanation on canon law as it relates to private or personal vows

What is your evidence that bishops actually can regulate the posture of reception to the detriment of universal law? When the new translation came out of the Novus Ordo Missal was published, a lot of commentary noted that the rubric for communion changed in a way which appeared to prevent/discourage the previous discouragement of kneeling by ministers at the time of reception.

Well, with regards to kneeling, he doesn't have that right, as that's been settled by Rome. But we can see clearly that bishops have a right to dictate at least some liturgical postures when we look at the ad orientem debate (see: https://www.pillarcatholic.com/p/more-us-bishops-require-permission). As for whether this can be done "to the detriment of universal law," that I don't know, and I don't think it factors into the general thrust of my answer, though it does apply in many particular circumstances.

Wow! I did not know that vows and oaths were in canon law.  Actually, I'm not sure if I made a vow or an oath now.  Maybe I should ask another question.  Basically, in the scouting organization I was a leader in, I promised to always receive communion kneeling and on my tongue.  It would seem that if it were an oath, that I would be freed from it by virtue of no longer being a member of that organization.

@PeterTurner a vow is a binding of the will to do or omit to do something. An oath is invoking God in witness of truth.

St. Clement of Rome basically states that doctrinal accuracy may not always be found in the majority and a person who leaves a Church because of that will attain to great honour and glory in the Lord provided he turned out right which is even mentioned by St. Irenaeus of Lyons as an authentic tradition from the apostles referring to this writing next containing this verse which almost sounds like a prophecy  and states that sometimes the person who leaves the church could be more accurate doctrinally despite the ruling of the majority.
This is a clear proof of freewill practice which God has allowed even in the area of doctrinal accuracy in a Church agreeing to Christ  .
St. Clement of Rome writes,

Who then among you is noble-minded? Who compassionate? Who full of love? Let him declare, If on my account sedition and disagreement and schisms have arisen, I will depart, I will go away wherever ye desire, and I will do whatever the majority commands; only let the flock of Christ live on terms of peace with the presbyters set over it. He that acts thus shall procure to himself great glory in the Lord; and every place will welcome him. For the earth is the Lord's, and the fullness thereof. These things they who live a godly life that is never to be repented of, both have done and always will do.
St. Clement of Rome (died c. 99/100AD).1 Clement, Chapter 54.

St. Irenaeus of Lyons writes:

for there were many still remaining who had received instructions from the apostles. In the time of this Clement, no small dissension having occurred among the brethren at Corinth, the Church in Rome dispatched a most powerful letter to the Corinthians, exhorting them to peace, renewing their faith, and declaring the tradition which it had lately received from the apostles,”
Against Heresies, Book 3, Chapter 3.


Always follow your conscience. Try to understand why Church Leaders might want you to change your behavior - but ultimately if they are instructing you to act in a manner that conflicts with your conscience and you do it anyways: that is sin for you.
